# symfony2 isValid() method always returns true

Tags: php, mysql, validation, symfony

I'm validating my data before saving them into the database, but so far, when javascript validation is turned off, i can't detect whether object is valid or not. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
$editForm = $this->createEditForm($post, $category_id, $section_id, $topic_id);
      $editForm->handleRequest($request);

if ($editForm->isValid()) {
          $em->flush();
          return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('topic_show', array('category_id'=> $category_id, 'section_id'=> $section_id, 'id'=> $topic_id)));
      }
```

unfortunatelly method isValid() returns true everytime and then i get error from mysql.

I tried different approach, taken from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html)

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
            $errors = $validator->validate($post);

        if (count($errors) > 0) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
            /*
             * Uses a __toString method on the $errors variable which is a
             * ConstraintViolationList object. This gives us a nice string
             * for debugging
             */
            $errorsString = (string) $errors;

            return new Response($errorsString);
        }
```

But it is also not working...

UPDATE

my 'content' attribute which is causing the error

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;
```

Comment: Do you have any [`Constraints`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#basic-constraints) in your `Entity` or `FormType`?

Comment: no, it looks like in symfony any attribute is required by default

Comment: No, you have to use [`NotBlank()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html) or [`NotNull()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html) to make field being required.

Comment: but i get mysql error telling me that 'content' column cannot be null and i have no Assert in my model. i will update my question

Comment: _Also note that setting the required option to true **will not result in server-side validation to be applied**._  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options

Comment: ok, i will try it your way:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set [`Constraints`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#basic-constraints) in your `Entity` or you can do it in your `FormType` [manually](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation) to set validation rules for your fields.

Here is an example

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

...

 /**
  * @var string
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
  * @Assert\NotBlank(
  *      message = "Your error message here if content is empty"      
  * )   
  */
 private $content;
```

Comment: but i dont want content to be nullable:) i want it to be validated for NOT being null

Comment: Then add Constraints.

Comment: any idea how to later display this message?

Comment: By using `{{ form_errors(form) }}` - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-error-output

Comment: okay but if the form is not valid i redirect to edit page, should i just send it in params?

Comment: Better set action to your edit page, and if success, user will be redirected somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60758/discussion-between-leo-and-mr-smith).